# Para que servem os colchetes em Python?

Tags: python

Vi um código que tem algumas funções entre `[]`. Para que serve esse colchetes?

Pensava que os colchetes serviam para criação de listas e manipulação de string.

```
print('Total de nulos por Variável: ', df.isnull().sum()[df.isnull.sum() > 0].sort_values(ascending= False))
```

Comment: **A pergunta é boa.** É a oportunidade de falar um pouco da lib [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) e como manipular o modelo de dados python através de funções como [`object.__getitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__getitem__) e [`object.__setitem__(self, key, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__setitem__).